# delete contents of multiple selected cells datagridview in C++/CLI

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, c++-cli

I'm trying to delete the string contents of all my selected cells when I click on a button in a Windows Form. The button event hook calls the following function:

Code:

```
    void deleteHighlightedRows(DataGridView^ dgv)
     {

         if (dgv->SelectedCells->Count > 0)
         {
             for (int i = 0; i < dgv->SelectedCells->Count; i++)
             {
                 dgv->SelectedCells[i]->Value = "";
             }
         }
     }
```

This function is called whenever a button is clicked, however whenever there are multiple rows selected, the count of the selected rows are always zero.

Any help/pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: I think you may have a typo in your post.  In your code you are using `SelectedCells` but at the end of your question you reference `SelectedRows`.  Regardless, I can't reproduce the behavior of the `SelectedCells` OR `SelectedRows` count being zero when multiple rows or cells are selected.  Please provide a little more info and I can likely help you out.

Comment: Also, I'm able to reproduce your code in C# and I'm able to get the values to clear out successfully.